# Changes does not appear on live server, WordPress  page template

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have created a simple WordPress page template. I am working on live server. But something very strange is happening. When I make a change in the following code, that change does not appear on anywhere except in a browser where I'm logged in as an administrator.
I have tried to clear the cache, but the problem is same.

For example: I add a new tag in page `<h2>Recent Posts</h2>`. This recent post will appear in Firefox where I'm logged in an administrator. It won't appear on my other computer's Firefox. Not in any other browser.

Note:
- Clearing cache didn't work for me.
- The page is published.
- Source code of the page does not show any change either.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: testpage
    */
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <base target="_parent" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
        <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <ul class="latest_posts">
                <?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '10' );
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $recent_posts as $post ):
                ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post["ID"])?>" title="<?php echo $post["post_title"]?>" >
                            <?php echo $post["post_title"]?>
                        </a>
                        <span class="date"><?php the_time('d-M-Y')?></span>
                    </li>
                <?php
                    endforeach;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a caching plugin installed by someone in the backend. I have changed its settings to not to cache pages, and now I can see changes.